# Is it possible to point a full URL to another server?

Tags: php, html, dns, server, cross-domain

Bit of a weird one.

One of my clients has a shared hosting server which he hosts his website on lets say:

http://www.example.com

To develop a web application for him I have had to use a different server lets say 255.255.255.255 which allows SSH access.

My client wants http://www.example.com/portal to essentially "point" or display the portal & web pages etc from server 255.255.255.255.

I know you can point domains but I have no idea where to start on something like this, any help or suggestions would be appreciated

J x

Comment: A really crude solution would be to put a `index.html` file at example.com/portal with an iframe referencing 255.255.255.255.

Answer (score 1):

1. Better: place it on a subdomain: http://portal.example.com
2. Worse: proxy all request from http://www.example.com/portal to your site. But you need access to web server config - unlikely shared hosting will allow you to do it. 
   Or you need your own hosting like VPS and so on.

Answer (score 1):

A plain 301 redirect comes to mind:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.com/portal$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://255.255.255.255/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This should obviously go into the .htaccess on www.example.com

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `.htaccess` file placed in the root of the www.example.com site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^portal/?(.*)$ http://255.255.255.255/$1 [P]
```